# how can i input php in mysql without repeat?

Tags: php

I want to add some random number that created by PHP to my SQL without repeat.
I use this code to create 14 length random:

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        $n1 = rand(100000,999999);
        $n2 = rand(100000,999999);

        $pincode = (string)$n1.(string)$n2;
    echo $pincode;
    echo nl2br("$pincode\n");
```

Now I want to input created a number in My SQL and ignore the repeated number. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: Stop posting the same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17716441/1920232. Edit your original one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use timestamp. It shall always be unique and no chance of duplicacy.

Comment: In that case there can be two entries with same value, that is not what author has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Afroz, timestamp is probably unique, but very predicteable ;-)

This might be interesting: [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)